# Adding an object to an object list C++/CLI

Tags: list, object, c++-cli

I'm trying to add an object to my object list. But I got several problems with it.

I have 2 classes:

Element.h

```
#pragma once
#include "LinePiece.h"

using namespace System::Collections::Generic;

ref class Element
{
public:
    Element();

    //properties
    System::String^ ON;                     //order nummer
    System::String^ MO;                     //order merk
    System::String^ SN;                     //element nummer
    System::String^ RS;                     //element afwerking
    System::String^ OW;                     //wapeningspatroon
    System::String^ CN;                     //element calculation number
    int el_length;                          //element lengte
    int el_width;                           //element hoogte
    int el_beginX;                          //element beginpunt
    int el_concrete_height;                 //element hoogte beton
    int el_iso_height;                      //element isolatie hoogte
    System::String^ el_weight;              //element gewicht
    List<LinePiece^>^ listLinePieces;       //lijst met contouren       
};
```

and my second class: LinePiece.h

```
#pragma once

ref class LinePiece
{
private :
    System::String^ Type;
    int ElementNr;
    int Status;
    int X, Y, X2, Y2;
    int Diameter;
    System::String^ Text;
public:
    LinePiece();

    //Constructor CO
    LinePiece(System::String^ a_type, int a_ElementNr, int a_Status, int a_x, int a_y)
    {
        Type = a_type;
        ElementNr = a_ElementNr;
        Status = a_Status;
        X = a_x;
        Y = a_y;
    }       
    //Constructor LN met tekst
    LinePiece(System::String^ a_type, int a_ElementNr, int a_Status, int a_x, int a_y, int a_x2, int a_y2, System::String^ a_text)
    {
        Type = a_type;
        ElementNr = a_ElementNr;
        Status = a_Status;
        X = a_x;
        Y = a_y;
        X2 = a_x2;
        Y2 = a_y2;
        Text = a_text;
    }
```

and my last file I have ReadPlotFile.h where I fill my list.

```
List<Element^>^ ReadPlotFile::GetElementInfo(List<String^>^ a_FileBuffer)
{
    List<Element^>^ ElementList = gcnew List<Element^>;
    List<LinePiece^>^ LinePieceList = gcnew List<LinePiece^>; 

    Type = "LN";
    EleNr = System::Convert::ToInt32(ElementNumber);
    Status = 0;
    Line = "BO    55041        0    61920        0"; // a line out of a file

    X1 = System::Convert::ToInt32(Line->Substring(3, 9));
    Y1 = System::Convert::ToInt32(Line->Substring(12, 9));
    X2 = System::Convert::ToInt32(Line->Substring(21, 9));
    Y2 = System::Convert::ToInt32(Line->Substring(30, 9));  

    LinePiece lpObject(Type, EleNr, Status, X1, Y1, X2, Y2);
    LinePieceList->Add(lpObject); // ERROR HERE 
}
```

I know the error is complaining about adding an `LinePiece` object into my list (since my list is for `LinePiece^`).
Error: C2664 'void System::Collections::GenericList::Add(LinePiece ^)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'LinePiece to Linepiece^'

But when I remove the `^` in my List. (like: `List<LinePiece>^ LinePieceList<LinePiece>;` it gives me the following error: "LinePiece" is not a valid generic argument.

How can I solve this problem and be able to add my LinePiece object to my list?

Comment: I just noticed I didn't add a constructor to my Element class but that shouldn't be the problem for this one.

Comment: A pretty simple problem, lpObject is missing the ^.  How's that tutorial going?  No point in getting bogged down by such minor issues, not for us either.

Comment: When I do `LinePiece^ lpObject(Type, EleNr, Status, X1, Y1, X2, Y2);` it's still not working: `'intializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to LinePiece^` and `a value of type "System::String ^"  cannot be used to initialize  an entity of type "LinePiece ^"`

Comment: You already know what `gcnew` looks like.

Comment: yea that was it. I was a bit confused because I'm not used to the C++/CLI combination. It's 50/50 C#/C++ for me. where `LinePiece lpObject(...);`works in C++, it doesn't for C# (and neither for C++/CLI it seems). in C# it's also normal to create an object first with `new`.